# If a relationship is (logically) deleted, is this marked in the link table or just the satellite table(s)?

Tags: foreign-key, data-warehouse, delete, data-vault

I'm learning about the Data Vault data warehousing approach, and so far the examples I've seen have a `DateLoaded` or similar field in all tables (hub, link, and satellite), but a `DateExpired` or `EndDate` field only in satellite tables.  If a relationship is deleted in a source system, should this be recorded only by setting the `DateExpired` field in the link's satellite table(s), or should one also maintain a `DateDeleted` field in the link table?

Note that I'm asking about "better" from a "Data Vault best practices" perspective.  For a specific application there may be good reasons to favor one approach or the other.